# how to passing parameter to index and custom route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass parameters to index function and if the parameter is not, redirect to home page. i added custom route also. where did i miss the code?

```
$route['main/(:any)'] = 'main/index/'; // looks like has a mistake
```

www.example.com ->when deafult index function

www.example.com/females ->when deafult index has string parameter 'female'

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index($gender) {  

  load->view('inc/header_view');

  if((isset($gender)) && ($gender =='female')){ 

    $this->load->view('female_view');

  } else {

    $this->load->view('female_view');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following code

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index($gender="") {  

  if($gender == "")
  {
     $this->load->view('home');

  } else {

    $this->load->view('female_view');
  }
}
```

Also as you mentioned to get this URL to work  `www.example.com` & `www.example.com/females` , you need to add following into your routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/index/$1';
```

Let me know in case of any queries

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like

```
$route['main'] = 'main/index'; 

$route['main/(:any)'] = 'main/index/$1';
```

Or you can use uri segments.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri%20segments#CI_URI::segment